# How to use Wake-on-LAN if system is in shutdown mode with connected LAN

Tags: wakeonlan

I've tried to the configuration i.e., Wake-on-LAN for sleep, but this option is failed for S5 (ACPI soft-off).

Can anyone suggest? how to enable Wake-on-LAN so system can boot from S5.

Comment: I guess you mean ACPI state S5 (soft-off). Wake-on-LAN should work from a soft-off state.

Comment: Maybe a [hint here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Other_machine_states_and_LAN_wakeup_signals): *"To allow wakeup from powered-down state S5, wakeup on PME (Power Management Event) is also required."*